# How do bit-torrent streaming clients enforce chunk ordering?

Tags: streaming, bittorrent

I am curious as to how some bit-torrent clients can receive chunks in order, like streaming clients do. I've always known BT clients to receive data chunks randomly and sequencing not to be guaranteed. So how do BT streaming clients manage to receive chunks in order? Is there an option defined in the protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client chooses the order that it downloads. When it connects to a peer it requests a specific block. A standard bit torrent client will choose a random block from a list of remaining blocks. This maximises the number of distributed copies. A streaming bit torrent client will request blocks in order. Thus making the file playable earlier, but creating a scenario with many peers, but very few distributed copies thus putting more pressure on fewer hosts.

Comment: Thanks @szatmary. That's clearly what I was missing to understand how it works.